# conflict between existing script and webview

Tags: winforms, webview2

I am using .Net core winforms with webview2. When I call CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString , I got error :

```
*VM7:1  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.*
    at EmbeddedBrowserWebView.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:40673)
```

in below code, which is coming from webview2 implementation:

```
                    embeddedBrowserWebView.addEventListener("message", native_event=>{
                    if (logNativeEvent)
                        console.log("native event:", native_event);
                    let eventArg = new Event("message");
                    Object.defineProperty(eventArg, 'data', {
                        value: JSON.parse(native_event.data)
                    });
                    Object.defineProperty(eventArg, 'source', {
                        value: webview
                    });
                    webview.dispatchEvent(eventArg);
```

So I think object Event is conflicting with one of own classes, which is not possible to change.
What is possible to do? Is it possible to modify webview2 JS to use another names?